# NativeScript Firebase es6 promises weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript, es6-promise

I'm trying to chain 2 Firebase queries using promises because I need the result of first query to get the second. Here is the structure of the 2 queries:

QUERY FOR VALUE A:

```
    private getValueA(){
    var queryEvent = (result):void  =>{
        console.dump(result);
        this._valueA = result.value;
    }
    return firebase.query(
        queryEvent,
        FirebaseValueAPath, 
        {
            singleEvent : true,
            orderBy : {
                type: firebase.QueryOrderByType.CHILD,
                value: 'since' 
            }
        });
    }
```

QUERY FOR VALUE B:

```
    private getValueB{

        let FirebaseValueBPath :string = this._valueA
        var queryEvent = (result) :void =>{
            console.dump(result);
            if(result.value){
                this._valueB = result.value;
            }
        }
        return firebase.query(
            queryEvent,
            FirebaseValueBPath,
            {
                singleEvent : true,
                orderBy : {
                    type    : firebase.QueryOrderByType.CHILD,
                    value   : 'since'
                }
        });
    }
}
```

I then try to chain them together by doing the following :

```
constructor(){
    this.getValueA().then(
     (success) :void => {
    this.getValueB();
   });
}
```

The result of this is the following :

1. For some reason `console.log(result)` inside **getValueB**
   function gets printed **before** console.log(result) inside
   **getValueA** function (why??)
2. `this.valueA` is `undefined` in `getValueB`, making my query useless
3. App crashes

What is wrong with my code? Should I be using another approach for this problem?
Thank you in advance for looking into this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using promises you have to resolve the result in your callback.
Please find the code below :

```
class GetData {
    constructor() {
        this.getValueA()
            .then(resultA => this.getValueB(resultA));
    }

    getValueA() {
        return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
            firebase.query(
                (result) => {
                    resolve(result.value); // Resolve => returns the result
                },
                FirebaseValueAPath, 
                {
                    singleEvent : true,
                    orderBy : {
                        type: firebase.QueryOrderByType.CHILD,
                        value: 'since' 
                    }
                }));
        });
    }

    getValueB(valueA: string) {
        return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
            firebase.query(
                (result) => {
                    resolve(result.value);  // Resolve => returns the result
                },
                valueA, 
                {
                    singleEvent : true,
                    orderBy : {
                        type: firebase.QueryOrderByType.CHILD,
                        value: 'since' 
                    }
                }));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This did it!! Thanks

Comment: One question though...isn't this considered an anti pattern? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: I didn't know the anti-pattern. I've learned something new, thanks ! After analyzing the github page in your link, i don't think that my answer is a, anti-pattern. Because the `firebase.query` does not return a `Promise` with the result. It's a function with result callback. So, if you want to use it in Promise way WITHOUT ANY EXTERNAL LIBRARY, you have to wrap it in `Promise` constructor. Otherwise, you could use the `promisify` library like mentionned in the github page.